# Bitrix24 injecting filter values with BX.Main.filterManager

Tags: javascript, bitrix

I'm trying to change a Bitrix grid filter with javascript. 
I can access the filter with `BX.Main.filterManager.getById("GRID_ID")`, can refresh the filter and the connected grid with `.applyFilter()` but I couldn't find a way to change them.

How can I get the current filters and add or remove any filters to that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var filter = BX.Main.filterManager.getById(BX.Tasks.GridActions.gridId);
    var values = filter.getFilterFieldsValues();

    // .. modify values as you wish .. 

    filter.getApi().setFields(values);
    filter.getApi().apply();
```